# creating new data frame by transforming csv

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a file "ts3.csv" that contains a column of data (with the first row as the title).
I would like to create a new data frame with two columns x and y... where each x is obtained by substituting a value of tst3 into an equation. Same for the values of the column y.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
ts3 <- read.csv("path/ts3.csv")
For i in 1:391 {
  t <- ts3[i]
  p <-data.frame(x = (t* 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi *sin(t * 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi)), y=(t* 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi *cos(t * 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi)))
}
Next i
attach(p)
plot(x,y)
```

here is the error message:

```
Error in t * 5 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> Next i
Error: unexpected symbol in "Next i"
> attach(p)
Error in attach(p) : object 'p' not found
```

Please help, new to R... thank you.

```
> dput(head(ts3))
structure(list(timestamp = 1:6), .Names = "timestamp", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of ts3 so we can see what you are working with. For example do dput(head(ts3)) and paste the output in your question.

Comment: `structure(list(timestamp = 1:6), .Names = "timestamp", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: `R` allows for vectorized code. I'm not sure you need to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Instead of trying to iterate through 390 different rows simply make it - `p<-data.frame(x=(ts* 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi *sin(ts * 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi)), y=(ts* 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi *cos(ts * 5 / 24 / 60 * 2 * Pi)))`. Additionally - you don't need to specify `Next i`. On top of that, never use `attach()`

Comment: Thank you, I think this is close to working. But now it says that "object `Pi` not found"... and when I try `> exists("Pi")
[1] FALSE`

Comment: try `pi` and not `Pi`